# Scroll to specific element in horizontal scroll bar - Ionic-2/3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a footer with multiple divs that can be scrolled horizontally. For horizontal scrolling I’ve used ion-scroll. Now if I click on any of these div then all the divs should get scrolled automatically so as to bring the clicked div to the center position of the footer view.

I tried scrollTo and scrollIntoView but these didn’t work. I need the help to get this implementation done.

the code I have implemented till now.

```
<ion-footer>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-scroll direction="x" scrollX="true" class="wide-as-needed" id="test" overflow-scroll="false">
        <div [attr.id]="'polygon-' + i" *ngFor="let item of myList; let i=index" (click)="OnDivClick(item)" class="PolygonDiv">
            <polygon [summaryList]="item"></polygon>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-toolbar>
```

I’m looping over a list to create multiple div which contain the custom component. On click on any of these divs I want that div to be scrolled automatically to the center of the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the ion-scroll to ion-content and made it's overflow-x value to scroll, then used scrollTO method to scroll to specific div.